# Can't create new connection to database

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Hello i'm a new user of oracle 12.1 c database, and oracle sql developer 19.1.
I have a problem with creating a new user, and making a connection with him.

I can connect to "sys" user as a "SYSDBA" role with connection name "admin", after log in i go to:
1. Oracle connection -> "admin" -> Other users -> Create user
 .I just follow this instruction https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/bidw/datamining/ODM11gR2-SetUp.htm#top 
and in section with creating a connection for data miner, i did exacly the same thing as in this instruction but when i click test it shows error: 
"Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

can u help me ?

Comment: Well ... provide correct username and password. LeTTEr CaSe MatTErs.

Comment: well i provide correct username and password ... and i use only lowercase letter.

Comment: Locate SQLNET.ORA file and see what's written for `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=???`

Comment: if you need to, just use sql developer to change the password in case you got it wrong or weren't sure about the case

Comment: "# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

" there is nothing like SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=???

Comment: Are you connecting to CDB or PDB, r a standalone DB: and are you creating a common user or a normal one? What role are you using for the new-user connection? Are you actually using SID or service name?

Comment: When i was creating databaase i uncheck "create as a container" if it is what you asking about, a user role i created is set to defoult.

Comment: so it is pluggable database.

Comment: on your new connection, you don't have the AS SYSDBA still checked do you? that would cause the error you're seeing even if your password is correct